# Capacity limit for GSI partition in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Every partition in the DynamoDB table has limited capacity of 3,000 RCU and 1,000 WCU. Does the same limit apply for GSI's **partition**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Global Secondary Indexes have the exact same partitions as base tables, and must conform to the limits you mentioned. For that reason, its suggested to have a high cardinality key for your index also.